# Prevent user adding a higher value in the input box

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am using a text input that allows only numbers, it also adds : after the first 2 characters. I now want to stop the user inputting a number higher than 24 for the first two characters and 60 for the second 2 characters after :.

Here's what I have so far.

I've managed to log when a number is bigger than 24, I've managed to get the first two and second two numbers but I can't work out how to check if the input number is higher than the max numbers allowed for each.

```js
// Max number values
const maxFirstTwo = 24;
const maxSecondTwo = 60;

const el = document.getElementById("inputbox");
const val = document.getElementById("inputbox").value;

// Limit to 5 characters from startTime
el.setAttribute("maxlength", 5);
el.setAttribute("inputmode", "numeric");

// Add : after 2 characters from inputTime
el.addEventListener("keydown", (eventObject) => {
    const length = eventObject.target.value.length;
    const keyCode = eventObject.keyCode;
    if (keyCode != 8 && length === 2) {
        eventObject.target.value += ":"
    }

    if (
        eventObject.key.length === 1 && eventObject.key !== '.' && isNaN(eventObject.key) && !eventObject.ctrlKey || 
        eventObject.key === '.' && eventObject.target.value.toString().indexOf('.') > -1
    ) {
        eventObject.preventDefault();
    }
    
    const typed = +eventObject.key;
    if (myArray0 > maxFirstTwo) {
    console.log('bigger than first two');
  }
  
  if(!isNaN(typed)) eventObject.preventDefault(); // Allow any non-number keys (backspace etc.)
  
  if ( +(eventObject.target.value + typed) <= maxFirstTwo) {
    el.value += typed
  } else {
    console.log(`Number too big! Max is ${maxFirstTwo}`)
  }

});

const myArray0 = val.split(":")[0];
const myArray1 = val.split(":")[1];

console.log(myArray0)
console.log(myArray1)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputbox">
```

Comment: There is an input type for numbers as well that has min and max attribtues to restrict which values can be entered. But since you mention 24 and 60 as values, I feel like you're making a time input, which conveniently, also exists. Any reason why you can't use the default number and time inputs?

Comment: I'm using a third party tool, it's still in development but there's a few items that have been missed, Time is one of them. For now I have to find a workaround until it is added.

Comment: And `<input type="time">` cannot be used while you wait for the 3rd party tool?

Comment: unfortunately not, the input is built into it. I can hack around it but I feel this is the best solution for the moment.